# Why object references are behaving differently?

Tags: java, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

What I am trying to do here is to swap two objects inside a method and outside the method. While I try to do it in a seperate method, the objects are NOT swapped and while done within the method, they are swapped. I dont understand what I am missing here. Here is the code snippet.

```
public class Swap {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Swap s = new Swap();
        s.testSwap();
    }   
    private void testSwap(){
        Animal a1 = new Animal("Lion");
        Animal a2 = new Animal("Crocodile");
        System.out.println("Before Swap:- a1:" + a1 + "; a2:" + a2);
        swapObjects(a1, a2);
        System.out.println("After Swap outside the method:- a1:" + a1 + "; a2:" + a2);
        Animal temp = new Animal("");
        temp = a1;
        a1 = a2;
        a2 = temp;
        System.out.println("After Swap within the method:- a1:" + a1 + "; a2:" + a2);
    } 
    public void swapObjects(Animal a1, Animal a2) {
        Animal temp = new Animal("");
        temp = a1;
        a1 = a2;
        a2 = temp;
    }
}

class Animal {
    String name;
    public Animal(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your method is doing nothing other than moving around references local to that method.  Please tell us what you want your swap method to actually be doing, and maybe someone can give you code for that.

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40501/2310289)

Comment: @ScaryWombat - Perfect. Exact answer I was looking for. Thanks !